# How to get array from base class on child class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance

Helo. I try to get multidimensional array from scriptA in scriptB using inheritance and it seems like after calling this array on scriptB, array is empty.

```
    public class ScriptA : MonoBehaviour
    {
        protected GameObject[,] boardFields = new GameObject[8, 8];
     
        void Awake()
        {
            boardFields[4, 0] = GameObject.Find("Canvas/Board/Fields/A4");
            Debug.Log(boardFields[4, 0]); //here i see in the console that the variable is not empty
            //rest of the code
        }
    }



    public class ScriptB : ScriptA
    {
        void Start()
        {
            Debug.Log(boardFields[4, 0]); //and here i get null in the console
        }
    }
```

I also checked another variables and it seems that the problem is only with arrays. How can i use this array in scriptB? Sorry for maybe stupid question but i just started with object programming

Comment: What is being executed first in the `ScriptB` instance? The  `void Awake()` or the `void Start()` ?

Comment: Do note that your array is dimensionated, but until the `Awake()` executes it would have no content despite its size being defined.

Comment: @Cleptus in the `ScriptB` there is only `void Start()`

Comment: @Cleptus I dont get it, in `void Awake()` i add to array a content `boardFields[4, 0] = GameObject.Find("Canvas/Board/Fields/A4");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in access modifiers.

```
void Awake()
{
}
```

defaults as a private method. So when Unity search the method in `ScriptB` via reflection it just does have access to them.

So try to use different access modifier like `protected` to inherit behaviour.

The other ways is to define `Awake()` in all classes in your hierarchy, or you can reuse code like below

```
public class ScriptA : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected GameObject[,] boardFields = new GameObject[8, 8];
     
    void Awake()
    {
        Setup();
        Debug.Log(boardFields[4, 0]); //here i see in the console that the variable is not empty
        //rest of the code
    }

    protected void Setup()
    {
        boardFields[4, 0] = GameObject.Find("Canvas/Board/Fields/A4");
    }
}

public class ScriptB : ScriptA
{
    void Awake()
    {
        Setup();
    }

    void Start()
    {
         Debug.Log(boardFields[4, 0]); //and here i get null in the console
    }
}
```

Comment: Encapsulate worked for me, thanks a lot!